# How to pass in client Certificate parameter when creating service fabric connection azure devops REST API

Tags: azure, rest, devops, azure-service-fabric

I am attempting to create a service fabric connection via the azure devops rest API, as documented here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/serviceendpoint/endpoints/create?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0

When attempting to define the authorization parameters, I have the following fields in my request:

```
    "authorization": {
    "parameters":{
        "certlookup":"Thumbprint",
        "servercertthumbprint": "{{certificateThumbprint}}",
        "certificate":"{{certname}}",
        "certificatepassword":null,
    },
    "scheme":"certificate"
},
```

This will create a service connection to the cluster, however it does not look like the 'client certificate' parameter (as shown in screenshot bellow) is parsed in anyhwhere. I also cant seem to find anywhere in the documentation that says how to do this.

How can I pass in the "Client Certificate" Value when using the REST API?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Below is the detailed view of the parameters which you can use for [creating Service Fabric Service Connection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/library/service-endpoints?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#sep-fabric):

[image]

Pls try to make your request like below (un tested) to make it work:

```
 "authorization": {
    "parameters":{
        "certlookup":"Thumbprint",
        "servercertthumbprint": "{{certificateThumbprint}}",
        "clientcertificatedata":"{{certname}}",
        "password":null,
    },
    "scheme":"certificate"
},
```

Please refer to [EndpointAuthorizationParameters Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualstudio.services.serviceendpoints.webapi.endpointauthorizationparameters?view=azure-devops-dotnet) for details about the parameters to use.

Comment: Sadly this does not appear to work, I am getting the following error:  `"Following fields in the service connection are not expected: clientcertificatedata.\r\nOnly fields that are defined in the service connection's contribution type as inputs can be specified.",`

Comment: Can you try with `clientcertificate`?

Comment: The correct parameter is acutlaly just "certificate".

Comment: If this answers helped you in identifying the parameters meanings and headed you to the right direction, can you mark it as an answer to help other community members?

Answer (score 0):

The correct parameter to specify this value is actually just "certificate".

The original request posted is correct, I was entering the name of the certificate rather than the encoding of it.